# Flexbox and alignment of wrapped items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox with wrapped items:

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 520px;
  height: 520px;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  background: gold;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container wrap">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
  <li class="flex-item">8</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0v54s2Lz/1/

I'd like 5, 6, 7, and 8 to be right below 1, 2, 3, and 4. But there is a gap. Flexbox is, presumably, trying to equalize the "row" heights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add

```
align-content: flex-start;
```

to your .flex-container.

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 520px;
  height: 520px;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-item {
  background: gold;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container wrap">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
  <li class="flex-item">8</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7LeL9mcd/

Answer (score -1):

remove `height: 520px;` from `.flex-container`, here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0v54s2Lz/2/)